# trying to freeze the labels only while moving horizontally (not while moving vertically) in tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, frontend

[image]There is a master window named top_wl. And frame_wl is created in it.
I have set of labels that are created in a frame_wl (which is on a canvas_wl) and also I am creating another small frame (fram_s) in master window (top_wl) which is on the separate canvas( canvas_s). another frame is created in the canvas_s ( named frame_s1). And i have created one label on fram_s( small frame). have set one horizontal scroll bar for canvas_wl alone .I have set  both the canvas_wl and canvas_s  on single vertical scroll bar (named : scroll_bar_v). The idea behind this is to freeze the labels in the small frame while moving horizontally where as it has moved with vertical scroll bar.
Now the problem is the labels on the small frame ( fram_s) is freezed on both vertical and horizontal movement. can some  body help me to solve the problem? or please tell me where I am going wrong ?

```
top_wl = tk.Tk()# tk.Tk()  
top_wl.title("Work Shop Layout")

fram_wl =tk.Frame(top_wl,width=1500,height=5000,bg = 'khaki1',relief= SUNKEN)

# Creating small frame

fram_s = tk.Frame(top_wl,width = 300,height = 500,bg = 'sky blue')
fram_s.place( x = 15, y = 90)

canvas_s = tk.Canvas(fram_s)
frame_s1 = tk.Frame(canvas_s)


l_12 = tk.Label(fram_s, text = 'Hello There',bd = 2, width = 30,bg = 'white',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "solid")
l_12. place(x = 10, y = 30)

# finished samll frame
canvas_wl = tk.Canvas(fram_wl,width=1500,height=4000,bg = 'lime green')

# top frame portion     
scroll_bar_v = tk.Scrollbar(fram_wl,orient='vertical') 
scroll_bar_v.config(command = canvas_wl.yview )


scroll_bar_h = Scrollbar(fram_wl,orient='horizontal') 
scroll_bar_h.config(command = canvas_wl.xview)
scroll_bar_h.pack( side = BOTTOM, fill = X )


t1 = tk.Label(fram_wl)#, text = "Hello There: Number_1",width = 50,height = 100,bg = 'Sky blue',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "sunken") #(x = 710, y = 50)


scroll_bar_v.pack( side = RIGHT, fill = Y ) 
t1.pack(side = RIGHT)

scrollable_frame_wl = tk.Frame(canvas_wl,bg = 'moccasin')#, bg = 'cyan2')
canvas_wl.create_window(0, 0, window=scrollable_frame_wl, anchor='nw')

left_wl = tk.Frame(scrollable_frame_wl, borderwidth=2, height = 5000,width = 10000,relief="sunken") #
left_wl. pack(side = 'left',padx=10, pady=10)


left_wl.pack_propagate(0)   

scrollable_frame_wl.update()

canvas_s.configure(yscrollcommand = scroll_bar_h.set,scrollregion = canvas_s.bbox("all"))
canvas_s.create_window((0,0),window =frame_s1, anchor = 'nw' ) 

canvas_wl.configure(xscrollcommand= scroll_bar_h.set,yscrollcommand= scroll_bar_v.set,scrollregion=canvas_wl.bbox("all")) 
canvas_wl.pack(fill = 'both')


fram_wl.pack()

top_wl.mainloop()
```

Comment: I didn't get you can you rephrase. Also, add an image for an explanation. I am finding it difficult to keep track of all the variables throughout your question.

Comment: I hope it is clear now.

Comment: I see mess in your code and maybe this makes that I found two mistakes - (1) you create `canvas_s` but you don't display it ie. `canvas_s.pack()` - so if you even scroll canvas then you can see it (2) you add label using `place()` so you can't move it with `canvas`. You would have to add it to canvas using `create_window(label,...)`

Answer (score 0):

This code scroll vertically both canvas and horizontally only bigger canvas.

There was mess in code so I organized code in different way to make some order.

First create scrollbars (which will be used by both canvas)

Next I create bigger frame with canvas and inner frame.

Next in the same way I create smaller frame with canvas and inner frame.

Next I add some elements to inner frames - in both I add label at the top and at the bottom of inner frame. This way I will see if it scroll to the end.

And finally I assign scrollbars to canvas to move them. Next I assign canvas to scrollbars to resize scrollbars to correct size.

And it works

There is only one problem. At this moment both frames shows only 1/3 of canvas height - so vertical scrollbar need to show slider with the same size (1/3 height) - but when you resize window then bigger frame show more canvas and scrollbar also show longer slider but smaller frame still show 1/3 of canvas and it would need smaller slider - and it would make conflict. It would display longer slider for short time (for bigger frame) and next longer slider for longer time (for shorter frame). Resizing also makes problem when you scroll down - first it shows bottom label in bigger frame but it still need mouse move to show bottom label in smaller frame.

I don't see good solution for this conflict - eventually you would have to resize smaller frame to show the same proporiton of canvas.

---

```
import tkinter as tk
 
top_wl = tk.Tk()
top_wl.title("Work Shop Layout")

# --- scrolls outside big frame (directly in window) ---

scroll_bar_v = tk.Scrollbar(top_wl, orient='vertical') 
scroll_bar_v.pack(side='right', fill='y')

scroll_bar_h = tk.Scrollbar(top_wl, orient='horizontal') 
scroll_bar_h.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')

# --- big frame (directly in window)  ---

# external frame
fram_wl = tk.Frame(top_wl, width=500, height=500, bg='khaki1', relief='sunken')
fram_wl.pack(side='right', expand=True, fill='both')
fram_wl.pack_propagate(False)  # don't resize external frame to canvas size

# inne canvas with size bigger then external frame
canvas_wl = tk.Canvas(fram_wl, width=1500, height=1500, bg='lime green')
canvas_wl.pack(fill='both')

# inner frame with size bigger then frame (scrollbars will use this size to scroll it)
scrollable_frame_wl = tk.Frame(canvas_wl, width=1500, height=1500, bg='moccasin')#, bg = 'cyan2')
canvas_wl.create_window(0, 0, window=scrollable_frame_wl, anchor='nw')

# --- small frame (inside big frame so it doesn't hide scrollbars when window is smaller) ---

# external frame 
#fram_s = tk.Frame(top_wl, width=300, height=300, bg='sky blue') # when it is directly in top_wl then it may hide scrollbars when window is smaller
fram_s = tk.Frame(fram_wl, width=300, height=300, bg='sky blue')
fram_s.place(x=0, y=100)
fram_s.pack_propagate(False)  # don't resize external frame to canvas size

# inne canvas with size bigger then external frame
canvas_s = tk.Canvas(fram_s, width=900, height=900, bg='blue')
canvas_s.pack()

# inner frame with size bigger then frame (scrollbars will use this size to scroll it)
scrollable_frame_s = tk.Frame(canvas_s, width=900, height=900, bg='red')#, bg = 'cyan2')
canvas_s.create_window(0, 0, window=scrollable_frame_s, anchor='nw')

# ---

# add to inner frame in frame WL
label_wl_1 = tk.Label(scrollable_frame_wl, text='WL-Frame Top', bd=2, width=30, bg='white', font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'), relief="solid")
label_wl_1.place(x=10, y=30)
label_wl_2 = tk.Label(scrollable_frame_wl, text='WL-Frame Bottom', bd=2, width=30, bg='white', font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'), relief="solid")
label_wl_2.place(x=10, y=1500-30)

#label_wl_1.pack()

# add to inner frame in frame S
label_s_1 = tk.Label(scrollable_frame_s, text='S-Frame Top', bd=2, width=30, bg='white', font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'), relief="solid")
label_s_1.place(x=10, y=30)
label_s_2 = tk.Label(scrollable_frame_s, text='S-Frame Bottom', bd=2, width=30, bg='white', font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'), relief="solid")
label_s_2.place(x=10, y=900-30)
#label_s_1.pack()

# --- set scrollbars to move canvas ---

# to scroll vertically both canvas 
def scroll_two_canvas(*args):
    #print(args)
    canvas_s.yview(*args)
    canvas_wl.yview(*args)
scroll_bar_v.config(command=scroll_two_canvas)  # it has to scroll two canvas

# to scroll horizontally one one canvas 
scroll_bar_h.config(command=canvas_wl.xview)    # it scroll only one canvas

# --- set canvas to resize scrollbars ---

# to update scrollbars when canvas is moved 
canvas_wl.configure(xscrollcommand=scroll_bar_h.set)
canvas_wl.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_bar_v.set)
# do't use it because it will conflict with previous 
#canvas_s.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_bar_v.set)

# get current size of element on canvas - if elements on canvas may change size (inner frame can change size) then you may need `bind('<Configure>')`
canvas_wl.configure(scrollregion=canvas_wl.bbox("all"))
canvas_s.configure(scrollregion=canvas_s.bbox("all"))

#def update_config(event):
#    print(event)
#    canvas_wl.configure(scrollregion=canvas_wl.bbox("all"))
#    canvas_s.configure(scrollregion=canvas_s.bbox("all"))

#top_wl.bind('<Configure>', update_config)

# ---

top_wl.mainloop()
```

[image]

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Code which resize smaller frame when bigger frame changes height. This way both frames shows the same percent of canvas height and scrollbar works better.

```
import tkinter as tk
 
top_wl = tk.Tk()
top_wl.title("Work Shop Layout")

# --- scrolls outside big frame (directly in window) ---

scroll_bar_v = tk.Scrollbar(top_wl, orient='vertical') 
scroll_bar_v.pack(side='right', fill='y')

scroll_bar_h = tk.Scrollbar(top_wl, orient='horizontal') 
scroll_bar_h.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')

# --- big frame (directly in window)  ---

# external frame
fram_wl = tk.Frame(top_wl, width=500, height=500, bg='khaki1', relief='sunken')
fram_wl.pack(side='right', expand=True, fill='both')
fram_wl.pack_propagate(False)  # don't resize external frame to canvas size

# inne canvas with size bigger then external frame
canvas_wl = tk.Canvas(fram_wl, width=1500, height=1500, bg='lime green')
canvas_wl.pack(fill='both')

# inner frame with size bigger then frame (scrollbars will use this size to scroll it)
scrollable_frame_wl = tk.Frame(canvas_wl, width=1500, height=1500, bg='moccasin')#, bg = 'cyan2')
canvas_wl.create_window(0, 0, window=scrollable_frame_wl, anchor='nw')

# --- small frame (inside big frame so it doesn't hide scrollbars when window is smaller) ---

# external frame 
#fram_s = tk.Frame(top_wl, width=300, height=300, bg='sky blue') # when it is directly in top_wl then it may hide scrollbars when window is smaller
fram_s = tk.Frame(fram_wl, width=300, height=300, bg='sky blue')
fram_s.place(x=0, y=100)
fram_s.pack_propagate(False)  # don't resize external frame to canvas size

# inne canvas with size bigger then external frame
canvas_s = tk.Canvas(fram_s, width=900, height=900, bg='blue')
canvas_s.pack()

# inner frame with size bigger then frame (scrollbars will use this size to scroll it)
scrollable_frame_s = tk.Frame(canvas_s, width=900, height=900, bg='red')#, bg = 'cyan2')
canvas_s.create_window(0, 0, window=scrollable_frame_s, anchor='nw')

# ---

# add to inner frame in frame WL
label_wl_1 = tk.Label(scrollable_frame_wl, text='WL-Frame Top', bd=2, width=30, bg='white', font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'), relief="solid")
label_wl_1.place(x=10, y=30)
label_wl_2 = tk.Label(scrollable_frame_wl, text='WL-Frame Bottom', bd=2, width=30, bg='white', font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'), relief="solid")
label_wl_2.place(x=10, y=1500-30)

#label_wl_1.pack()

# add to inner frame in frame S
label_s_1 = tk.Label(scrollable_frame_s, text='S-Frame Top', bd=2, width=30, bg='white', font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'), relief="solid")
label_s_1.place(x=10, y=30)
label_s_2 = tk.Label(scrollable_frame_s, text='S-Frame Bottom', bd=2, width=30, bg='white', font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'), relief="solid")
label_s_2.place(x=10, y=900-30)
#label_s_1.pack()

# --- set scrollbars to move canvas ---

# to scroll both canvas 
def scroll_two_canvas(*args):
    #print(args)
    canvas_s.yview(*args)
    canvas_wl.yview(*args)
   
scroll_bar_v.config(command=scroll_two_canvas)  # it has to scroll two canvas
scroll_bar_h.config(command=canvas_wl.xview)    # it scroll only one canvas

# --- set canvas to resize scrollbars ---
# to update scrollbars when canvas is moved 
canvas_wl.configure(xscrollcommand=scroll_bar_h.set)
canvas_wl.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_bar_v.set)
# do't use it because it will conflict with previous 
#canvas_s.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_bar_v.set)

# get current size of element on canvas - if elements on canvas may change size (inner frame can change size) then you may need `bind('<Configure>')`
canvas_wl.configure(scrollregion=canvas_wl.bbox("all"))
canvas_s.configure(scrollregion=canvas_s.bbox("all"))


# --- resize smaller frame when bigger frame changes height

# to keep current height and compare with new height when resize, and to calculate scale used to resize smaller framer
frame_wl_height = fram_wl['height']

def update_config(event):
    global frame_wl_height

    if event.widget == fram_wl: #'.':
        scale = event.height/frame_wl_height
        frame_wl_height = event.height
        fram_s['height'] = fram_s['height'] * scale

    #canvas_wl.configure(scrollregion=canvas_wl.bbox("all"))
    #canvas_s.configure(scrollregion=canvas_s.bbox("all"))

top_wl.bind('<Configure>', update_config)

# ---

top_wl.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate your help. 
However  from the above images we can saw that while moving the vertical scroll bar red color (canvas) is not moving with scroll bar. Whereas I want to move the red color frame (with labels) with vertical scroll bar but it should not be moved with horizontal scroll bar. I think now it clear.

Comment: well it seems I understand it in wrong way - I move object inside red frame (on inner canvas) - like in preview for bigger region. To move all red frame you would have to put red frame directly on bigger canvas using `create_window` (and it will move it automatically in both direction) and you would need to create function which keeps it in the same when you scroll horizontally - it should move it in opposite direction - when scrollbar move bigger canvas to left then code would have to move red frame to the right - and this way it would looks like it keep in place..